# How to "Step Into" or "Step Over" code while debugging an app in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, debugging, android-studio

I am trying to follow this [Debugging with Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html).

How do I Step Into or Step Over code?

Under the variables tab in debugger it just shows:
"Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8609',transport:'socket'"

The "Step Into", "Step Over" options are greyed out.
Do I pause execution and then Step Into or Step Over my code?

[image: After I click "Debug 'app'"]

Comment: Try killing adb and restart it again. Reconnect the device.

Comment: how do i step into or step over code ? i can't do that right now do i have to pause the execution and then step into or step over code ?

Comment: i can't see any variables nor can i step into or step over code ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to put a watch(see how a variable is modified) in Android Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057447/how-to-put-a-watchsee-how-a-variable-is-modified-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 5):

By default, step over is F8, step into is F7.

Comment: Such a simple question by @umar and thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need for your code to reach your breakpoint, then all debugging options should be available.

[image: App Ready to Debug]

My guess is that right now your code is still running in debug mode.
So either you'll have to set a better breakpoint or you'll have to advance your code to the current breakpoint.

Then, the next line to execute will no longer be "Breakpoint Red",
but instead be "Debug Blue" like `if (square.getTag() == tag)` is below:
[image: Line Debug Blue]

Yours is still "Breakpoint Red":
[image: Line Breakpoint Red]

You can then also use the following keyboard short cuts:
[image: Keyboard Debugging Shortcuts]

Answer (score 0):

To debug your app in Android Studio:

Open your project in Android Studio.
Click Debug  in the toolbar.
On the Choose Device window, select a hardware device from the list or choose a virtual device.
Click OK. Your app starts on the selected device.

For more detail refer link https://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html

Comment: yes that is what i am doing but i cannot see the variables and i cannot apply watches to them

Comment: bring your curse to that variable you will able see the value

Comment: what are you try to say

Answer (score 0):

do like this,~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[image]

Comment: ok how do i step into or step over the code ? by pausing it ?

Comment: i have added a breakpoint but the step into step over options are greyed out

Comment: when i pause execution of the code i can then see those options available

Comment: you mean you cann't add variables to watch? if program in debug mode "Add to Wathes" always avaliable to me.

Comment: i can add a watch now .. but it's showing Debug info unavailable

Comment: becase  variables lifetime is end