# How to (step over) or (step in) Debug Process in Android Studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have been traditionally using Eclipse like for more than 5 years and have done projects in Hybrid Web , Android , Blackberry , J2ME .

Well , the question is pretty simple . I am used keys F5,F6,and F8 for debugging my app process.
As , I am new to Android Studio . Kindly guide me what are the alternatives present . 
I have gone through the link ,
[Android Debugging Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34804948/how-to-step-into-or-step-over-code-while-debugging-application-in-android-studio)
 but it still does not convince me to only add watches , it was in eclipse also to Add watches or by using Expressions

Comment: Use F8 / F7 to step over and step in.

Comment: Why downvote ? for this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach the `debugger` and add `breakpoints` to the LOC, and then press F9 to move over the `breakpoints` and F8 for next line.
[Please check the link for details](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-studio.html)