# Keep watches in Android Studio after debug

Tags: android, android-studio

Sometimes when I enter many variables into Watches and after several times I debug an application, Android Studio then shows old variables (for instance, yesterday's).

How to save variables in Watches?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25057447/how-to-put-a-watch-see-how-a-variable-is-modified-in-android-studio

Comment: @JohnJoe, sorry, what do you mean? I use Android Studio for ages and know, how to add watches.