# Syncronizing static variables in inner class

Tags: java, android

basically i am trying to modify a static variable from an inner class and then i want to read that static variable but it's not being set properly (from what i've read, the problem might be that the program is running in multiple threads and the thread that is reading the static value might not get an update and only read a cache?) I tried setting my static variable to volatile but had no effect.

MainActivity ->

```
ApiManager.evaluateResponse(responseLoginCall, MainActivity.this);

    if(ApiManager.isExecutionSuccessful) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "We are in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

ApiManager ->

```
public class ApiManager  {

public static volatile boolean isExecutionSuccessful = false;

public static void evaluateResponse(Call<AuthResponse> responseCall, Activity activity) {
    responseCall.enqueue(new Callback<AuthResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<AuthResponse> call, @NotNull Response<AuthResponse> response) {
            if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                ApiManager.isExecutionSuccessful = true;
            } ...
    });
```

In this example isExecutionSucessful is false even if it goes through `ApiManager.isExecutionSuccessful = true;`

Comment: Are you sure the `response` is successful?

Comment: Yes, i even stepped it with a debugger, also put a toast inside it to double check

Comment: Can you add the `isExecutionSuccessful` [to watches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25057447/8498513) and see how the value of a variable modifies through debugging?

Comment: something i just saw that happened is that the instruction AFTER `ApiManager.evaluateResponse(responseLoginCall, MainActivity.this);` is being called before the evaluateResponse actually finishes, that might be the problem, is it possible to lock the MainActivity thread until the `ApiManager.evaluateResponse(responseLoginCall, MainActivity.this);` call ends?

Comment: For synchronization, you can make a synchronous call using `Response<AuthResponse> response = responseCall.execute()` instead of 'responseCall.enqueue ()'

Comment: Excellent, thanks!!! solved it by creating my own thread (to avoid NetworkOnMainThreadException) and using .execute(). If you can post an answer I can mark it as solved, i dont really know if i can mark your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`responseCall.enqueue()` asynchronously sends the request and notifies the callback of its response, so `ApiManager.evaluateResponse(responseLoginCall, MainActivity.this)` was called before the request completed `responseCall.enqueue()`.

I suggest making a synchronous call with the `responseCall.execute()` function.